# xargs -n option to achieve parallelism and less processing time

Tags: bash, xargs

I am trying to understand how i could use `xargs` `-n` option to loop over a csv file and run CURL operation to collect output to a file to achieve faster processing time .

**Example:**

I need to check webpages health based on a CSV file with URIs (1000s of them).

**URI.csv**

```
signup
account
edit
close
```

I am trying check their status in parallel, using :

> cat URI.csv | xargs -n1 -I {}   /bin/bash -c 'curl -I
>   http://localhost/{} &> /dev/null &&  echo "{},Online">>healthcheck.log
>   || echo "{},Offline">>healthcheck.log '

Would i be able to speed up processing by making `-n2` ? I am aware that i could use something like `-P4` to achieve parallelism, however, not able to understand how `-n` could be used for my use case.

Comment: `-n` alone doesn't do anything wrt. parallelism; you can *combine* it with `-P` towards that end.

Comment: BTW, using `-I {}` and then `{}` inside a `bash -c` argument can easily lead to a shell injection vulnerability. Don't ever do that. (Think about what happens if you have a URI that includes `$(rm -rf ~)`)

Comment: Also, `foo && bar || baz` acts like a ternary sometimes, but it's *not* a ternary operator -- the corner cases can kill you. Think about what happens if `foo` succeeds but then `bar` fails -- you can end up running `baz` *in addition to* `bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
xargs -d $'\n' -P2 -n2 \
  /bin/bash -c '
    for arg do
      if curl --fail -I "http://localhost/$arg" &>/dev/null; then
        printf "%s,Online\n" "$arg"
      else
        printf "%s,Offline\n" "$arg"
      fi
    done
  ' _ >>healthcheck.log <URI.csv
```

- `xargs -d $'\n'` tells GNU `xargs` to operate line-by-line, rather than splitting your input file into words, trying to honor quotes, and otherwise using much more complicated parsing than you presumably actually want.
- `xargs -P 2` specifies that you run two processes at a time. Tune this as you wish.
- `xargs -n 2` specifies that each process is given two URLs to run. Tune this as you wish.
- `bash -c '...' _ arg1 arg2` runs the script `...` with `_` in `$0`, `arg1` in `$1`, `arg2` in `$2`, etc. Thus, arguments appended by `xargs` become the positional arguments to the script, which `for arg do` iterates over.
- `foo && bar || baz` acts *a little* like `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi`, but it's not identical. See [BashPitfalls #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3).
- Note that we're only opening `healthcheck.log` for write *once*, for the entire compound command, rather than re-opening the file every time we want to write a single line to it.

Comment: Thanks for very detailed response including teaching me to write better bash script. It is really useful and appreciated. When i executed the code, the output is written without newline separator -- do i need to do anything to get results printed in new line? Thanks!

Comment: Oops -- I made the mistake of using single quotes inside single quotes (used to hold the whole script). See the edit, using single-quotes for the format string (usually a bad practice, since format strings should be constant, but safe enough with this one).

Comment: Thanks for being patient with novice shell script developer:).

Comment: Hopefully last question -- Is it possible "pass" a variable to xargs? For example -- `localhost` -- i would like to make it $host which gets initialized beginning of the script.

Comment: `host=localhost xargs ...` will export an environment variable `host` for the duration of the command's execution. That's not specific to `xargs` -- works for any command. (Caveat: Note that `foo=bar echo $foo` doesn't do what you'd expect -- that's because the `echo` doesn't look at its environment for `foo`, but instead expects the shell calling it to perform expansions from local variables before the invocation). Or you can `export host` after initializing it earlier in your script; that'll make it available also.

Comment: You are appending to a single file in parallel. In general that is bad practice, because that opens for an obvious race condition if two processes append at exactly the same time. You do not elaborate on this, which makes it seem as if you have not thought of this. IF you have thought this through, you should probably comment the code with your thoughts.

Comment: Ole, I thought this code would not cause the problem based on Charles comment `Note that we're only opening healthcheck.log for write once, for the entire compound command, rather than re-opening the file every time we want to write a single line to it.` (Last bullet)

Comment: @kn9, that doesn't make this safe from the problem Ole is discussing. What makes it safe is that we're only doing a single write syscall per record, of less than a page in length. If we ran one `printf` of the argument, and another with the online/offline flag (f/e), the output could be interspersed.

Comment: @kn9, ...incidentally, this is something that almost might be described as a running disagreement -- I find GNU Parallel's source unreadable (and the resolutions to potential interactions between its multitude of features a source of substantial incidental complexity), and would prefer to use simple, limited tools rather than complicated, more capable ones. Ole is Parallel's author, and obviously has a different perspective. :)

Comment: "What makes it safe is that we're only doing a single write syscall per record, of less than a page in length." And this is the crux of the matter: I find it deceptive not to make this unambiguously clear. IMHO this should at least be so clear, that readers are not led to believe that it would be safe to, say, use 2 `printf`s instead of 1. This makes this solution not generally safe to use.

Comment: @kn9 Using well-tested tools is generally a good idea as long as one does not use them in ways they are designed for. The solution here fails to do that and fails to make that clear to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
cat URI.csv |
  parallel -j100 'curl -I http://localhost/{} &> /dev/null && echo {}",Online" || echo {}",Offline"' >>healthcheck.log
```

Or easier to read:

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
  if curl -I http://localhost/"$1" &> /dev/null ; then
    echo "$1,Online"
  else
    echo "$1,Offline"
  fi
}
export -f doit
cat URI.csv | parallel -j100 doit >>healthcheck.log
```

Adjust `-j100` to the number of jobs you want run in parallel.

By using GNU Parallel the jobs will be run in parallel, but the output to `healthcheck.log` will be serialized and you will never see a race condition, where two jobs write to the log simultaneously which can mess up the logfile. In this example `account` and `edit` wrote at the same time:

```
signup,Online
accouedit,Online
nt,Offline
close,Online
```

This will never happen to the output from GNU Parallel.

Comment: If you can generate the race condition discussed in the immediate case where we have a loop with a single `echo` or `printf` (of content less than 4KB in length), with default line-buffering of stdout, I'll be quite surprised.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why limit yourself to content less than 4KB in length? If that is a limitation of your solution, and you are aware of this, then would it not be right to warn the reader about that, too? (And yes: You can get mixing below 4 KB: See https://gist.github.com/ole-tange/88ae153797748b3618e2433377e2870a)